# react three fiber lock object position in canvas

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm new to Threejs and react-three-fiber. How to lock an object in canvas ( lock position, rotation ) when the perspective camera rotates and move. I want to make an object that avoids perspective camera movements and remain in a fixed position

[image: current preview]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use refs to access underlying objects](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/basic-animations#animating-with-refs), and thus modify their position, rotation, etc.

As [PerspectiveCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera) is an [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D), you can add this mesh as a child so that they move together.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';

const MyMesh = () => {
  const { camera } = useThree();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add mesh to camera
    const meshRef = ref.current;
    camera.add(meshRef);

    // Cleanup on unmount
    return () => {
      camera.remove(meshRef);
    };
  }, [camera, ref.current]);

  return <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 0, -5]} />;
};
```

Here, I'm accessing Fiber's camera through its context via the [`useThree`](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/hooks#use-three) hook.

Alternatively, you can copy the camera's properties every frame and apply an offset. This will result in the same display behavior.

You can access the renderloop via the [`useFrame`](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/hooks#use-frame) hook. This runs inside three, so there's no overhead within React. It's notable that you can access Fiber's context from within the hook's callback as well.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';

const MyMesh = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useFrame(({ camera }) => {
    // Move mesh to be flush with camera
    ref.current.position.copy(camera.position);
    ref.current.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);

    // Apply offset
    ref.current.translateZ(-5);
  });

  return <mesh ref={ref} />;
};
```